# Проверка соединения

Tags: c#, wcf

В сетевых приложениях есть такая штука когда клиент серверу или сервер клиенту по таймеру шлет тестовое сообщение для проверки не отвалился ли. Так вот как логичнее? Чтобы сервер клиенту слал или клиент серверу?

UPD. Детально по моему приложению. Пишу чат. Простой текстовый чат. И еще соответственно та сторона которая будет слать сообщения тоже ведь проверяет таким образом не отвалилась ли принимающая сторона. Например клиент шлет сообщения серверу, но если сервер вырубился то он получит ошибку при вызове, а это тоже как бы индикатор того что сервер вырубился. А сервер соответственно просто ждет получения сообщения тестового и если не получил убирает клиента из подключенных. Ну и все наоборот если принимающая сторона клиент.

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в клиент-серверных приложениях, но как по мне, надо отталкиваться от конкретной задачи. Например я бы думал так: если клиенту надо периодически проверять что-либо на сервере, то клиент отправляет сообщение. Если это какая-то MMO, то по идее уже должен сам сервер отправлять запрос, чтобы знать, отвалился ли пользователь (афк). Если отвалился - соответствующее сообщение над ним выкидывать. Хотя и тут можно сделать так, что запрос будет от пользователя идти. Всё на ваш вкус. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ кроется в не раскрытых вами деталях продукта, который вы разрабатываете, а точнее узлов в вашей инфраструктуры, другими словами - нарисуйте сколько у вас клиентов и серверов и все поймете сами:

UPD: в вашем случае я бы не закрывал соединение с сервером

Comment: обновил вопрос. Сервер один да. А клиентов может быть сколько угодно. Я никак это не ограничивал.

Comment: в вашем случае я бы не закрывал соединение с сервером

Comment: В смысле не закрывал? Когда не закрывал?

Comment: узлы после общения через сокет могут как закрыть его, так и не закрывать, если его не закрывать, то для повторной отпрваки данных соединение устанавливать не нужно

Comment: Ну во первых я пользуюсь WCF. А во вторых я опять таки не понимаю о чем вы... В каком месте они могут закрывать или не закрывать???

Comment: я не знаю тонкостей wcf, первый запрос на англоязычном стековерфлоу привел меня вот сюда, тут обсуджают как узнать закрылся ли сокет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338842/detect-socket-disconnect-in-wcf